# Android installation failed unknown error, will that also occur in the real device?

Tags: android, eclipse

Sometimes when i run the app from eclipse it gives

```
[2015-04-27 11:34:09 - MandiriTunasFinanceMobile] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2015-04-27 11:34:09 - MandiriTunasFinanceMobile] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2015-04-27 11:34:09 - MandiriTunasFinanceMobile] Launch canceled!
```

even when there is no error at all, could this happen when we install on real device?i mean not emulator

Comment: unplug and plug it again

Comment: the question is: could this happen on real device when we trying to install the app? I mean, is this only happening on emulator/eclipse , or when we publish the app this still could possibly occur?

Comment: only using eclipse, for example i don't have this issue using android studio

Comment: i see, do you know why this happening?